# What does the following note in Django's documentation mean?

Tags: django, postgresql, uuid

While browsing the [docs for Django's `UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield), I saw the following

> Lookups on PostgreSQL
>
> Using iexact, contains, icontains, startswith, istartswith, endswith,
>   or iendswith lookups on PostgreSQL don’t work for values without
>   hyphens, because PostgreSQL stores them in a hyphenated uuid datatype
>   type.

Is this something related to using `UUIDField`? Or is this a general note for any string values? If so, can someone provide an example of where these operations don't work with strings without hyphens?

Comment: I read that as applying only to UUIDField.

Comment: It's clearly in the section about the UUID field and explicitly mentions the `uuid` type. Yes, this is about UUIDs only.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is primarily about Django and how it handles uuid columns. However I must point out the the contention "PostgreSQL stores them in a hyphenated uuid datatype type" is at best misleading if  not incorrect. Postgres stores then as a uuid type it displays hyphenated but they can be queried with or without the hyphens. DEMO:

```
create table uuid_demo( uuid_col uuid, description test) ;

-- generate uuid to use in demo
select gen_random_uuid()
-- result f76fe42f-4328-479f-a446-93307fa21c1a

insert into uuid_demo(uuid_col, description)
   values ('f76fe42f-4328-479f-a446-93307fa21c1a'::uuid, 'With dashes') 
        , ('f76fe42f4328479fa44693307fa21c1a'::uuid, 'Without dashes'); 

-- with hyphens and with type cast 
select * 
  from uuid_demo
 where uuid_col = 'f76fe42f-4328-479f-a446-93307fa21c1a'::uuid; 

-- withou hyphens and with type cast
 select * 
  from uuid_demo
 where uuid_col = 'f76fe42f4328479fa44693307fa21c1a'::uuid; 

-- with hyphens and without type cast 
select * 
  from uuid_demo
 where uuid_col = 'f76fe42f-4328-479f-a446-93307fa21c1a';

-- without hyphens and without type cast
 select * 
  from uuid_demo
 where uuid_col = 'f76fe42f4328479fa44693307fa21c1a'; 


-- all 4 vereions produce the same result

 drop table uuid_demo;
```

So it is not Postgres that cannot handle uuid's without hyphens. In this case it is Django that can not handle uuid's without hyphens.